# C structure: fields copy order

Tags: c, struct, copy, language-lawyer

I have the following structure which presents some HW interface which requires the first field to be read first, only then the second one and then the third one.

```
struct example_s {
    uint32_t must_be_read_first;
    uint32_t must_be_read_second;
    uint32_t must_be_read_third;
};
```

I couldn't find in the C standard a chapter which defines the order of copy of structure fields in case, for example, *pass by value*. So to implement the required order, I manually read field by field

```
void handle_example(volatile struct example_s *ptr)
{
    struct example_s example = {
        .must_be_read_first = ptr->must_be_read_first,
        .must_be_read_second = ptr->must_be_read_second,
        .must_be_read_third = ptr->must_be_read_third,
    };

    // process 'example'
    ....
}

int main(void)
{
    volatile struct example_s *example_ptr;

    ...
    ...
    handle_example(example_ptr);
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

So my **question**:

Is there a way (special qualifiers for each struct field maybe?) that can be used in struct definition to force the copy order by the compiler, to be able to *pass the structure by value* like in the following code and fulfill the **read order** requirement:

```
void handle_example(struct example_s example)
{
    // process 'example'
    ....
}

int main(void)
{
    volatile struct example_s *example_ptr;

    ...
    ...
    handle_example(*example_ptr);
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing, copying the field in the required order programatically is the thing to do.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah, most likely you are right... but maybe there is some trick that we are not aware of... "no such thing" is also a possible answer to this question but I would like it to be based on the C standard.